# Grouping Items In A List View

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a Dictionary that is declared thusly:

```
Dictionary myDictionary<string, List<FCPort>> = new Dictionary<string, List<FCPort>>();
```

the key is a string representing a switch name.  The value is a list of port objects for that switch.  I am trying to add the items in the Dictionary to a ListView with this code:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<FCPort>> portpair in results)
        {             
            ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem(portpair.Key);
            foreach (FCPort port in portpair.Value)
            {
                item1.SubItems.Add(port.FCIDList[0]);
                item1.SubItems.Add(port.WWPNList[0]);
                item1.SubItems.Add(port.TextSerializePortName());
                this.ResultsListView.Items.Add(item1);

            }
        }
```

However, I get a run-time error basically saying that I have a duplicate item in the list.  That makes sense.  I am attempting to group by the dictinoary key (the switch name).  Is there a way to somehow group the items in the listview, or dynamically add Listviews to the GroupBox on the fly?  Basically add a new ListView for each key in the Dictionary?   I am still learning C# and forms are still new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use **LINQ lookup** to group by your key selector.
and extend your portpair to enumerable when add to into listview subitems

This is the code snippet I did sometimes hopefully could help you.

```
Dictionary<String, Country> dict = new Dictionary<string, Country>();
dict.Add("Toronto", Country.Canada);
dict.Add("New York", Country.US);
dict.Add("Vancover", Country.Canada);
dict.Add("Seattle", Country.US);
dict.Add("Fredericton", Country.Canada);

Lookup<Country,String> lookup = (Lookup<Country,String>) dict.ToLookup(pair =>pair.Value, pair => pair.Key);

 foreach (var countryGroup in lookup)
 {
    item = new ListViewItem(countryGroup.Key.ToString());
    item.SubItems.Add(string.Format("{0}", string.Join(",", countryGroup.Select(s => "@" + s))));
    lv.Items.Add(item);
    item = null;
 }
```